# Como logro colocar un Linearlayout encima de un scrollview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Necesito hacer una tabla donde tengo que scrollearla debido a que son demasiadas filas, la cabecera de la tabla debe ser estática y mostrarse cuando "scrolee". intente crear un linearlayout con los campos de la tabla y en otro linearlayout (que esta dentro de un scroll) , las ditintas filas. el problema es que el scrollview se superpone al  linearlayout con los campos de la tabla. estoy incluyendo un actionbar así que en la propiedad del primer linearlayout, lo coloco debajo de este.

[image: Esto es basicamente lo que sucede, el primer linearlayout esta detras de los cuadrados]

Comment: Puedes editar tu respuesta y agregar el código del layout?

Comment: Hey @Memphils revisa [ask], te sugiero agregar código en lugar de imagen del código o layouts

Answer (score -1):

Solo encierra el LinearLayout que deseas que tenga esa capacidad de navegación con el Scrolview. En tu código lo que está mal es que en tu ScrollView estas poniendo las dos etiquetas de cierre de los linear layouts cuando debería ser sola mente una.